# Flutter error while using late initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Im trying to connect my flutter web with discord oauth2 but i've got problem with late initializer.

Flutter suggests me to use "late" in:

```
Computed<ThemeData> _$currentThemeDataComputed;
```

After i add "late" then when im trying to run my website i've got this error:

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_$currentThemeDataComputed' has not been initialized.
```

Is there another way to fix it?

Comment: When you add `late` keyword it means that you need to instantiate before using it, most times you initialise it in the init method (StatefulWidget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prefer making data nullable. like `DataType? nullableVariableName`.

```dart
Computed<ThemeData>? _$currentThemeDataComputed;
```

Now you can check if the value is null or not while read it.

Dont use `!` directly without check null. Better way of handling will be

```dart
if(nullableVariableName!=null){
  /// use this variable 
}
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Now i've got this error ```══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER_MOBX ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MobXCaughtException was thrown From reaction of Observer of type
StatelessObserverElement.:
Unexpected null value.``` I guess it's going to be more complicated than I expected

Comment: make sure to initialize the variable